# How can I add Tukey TSF p value to plots?

Tags: r, plot, anova, tukey

I am trying to do make Tukey HSD plot by adding p values as already answered in one  of the previous questions, I am sharing the link to the questions already answered [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65947403/how-can-i-add-tukey-hsd-p-value-brackets-from-a-data-frame-to-ggplots-from-a-lis/78180252?noredirect=1#comment137828577_78180252).

I am trying plot something similar and am using the same code that is provided here at the end to my dataset.

But when I implement the code I do not get the desired output.

I am sharing my sample dataset from my analysis

```
Here is my dataset

structure(list(Type = c("CONTROLE", "CONTROLE", "CONTROLE", "CONTROLE", 
"CONTROLE", "CONTROLE", "CONTROLE", "CONTROLE", "CONTROLE", "CONTROLE", 
"CONTROLE", "CONTROLE", "CONTROLE", "CONTROLE", "CONTROLE", "CONTROLE", 
"CONTROLE", "CONTROLE", "CONTROLE", "CONTROLE"), Roof = c("Banco", 
"Banco", "Banco", "Banco", "Banco", "Banco", "Banco", "Banco", 
"Banco", "Banco", "Banco", "Banco", "Banco", "Banco", "Banco", 
"Banco", "Banco", "Banco", "Banco", "Banco"), value = c("32,248", 
"32,56", "33,08", "31,033", "30,292", "31,035", "30,919", "29,762", 
"32,017", "29,76", "32,371", "30,799", "30,574", "29,982", "30,909", 
"31,183", "32,387", "30,82", "31,272", "30,326")), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")

df2<-data.table(df2)
df2$type<-as.factor(df2$type)
df2$roof<-as.factor(df2$roof)
df2$value<-as.numeric(df2$value)
dfl <- split(df2, df2$Roof, drop=TRUE)


doPlots <- function(x, signif.cutoff=.05){
    set.seed(123)
    p1 <- ggplot(dfl[[x]], aes(x=Type, y=value, fill=Type)) +
        geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.7, linetype = 1, size = 1.1) +
        theme(legend.position = "none") +
        scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
        stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", size = 1.1, width = 0.4) +
        geom_jitter(aes(fill = Type), shape = 21, size = 4, stroke = 1) +
        ggtitle(x)
    a <- stats::TukeyHSD(stats::aov(value ~ Type, data = dfl[[x]]))[[1]]
    a <- stats::setNames(
        data.frame(
            do.call(rbind, strsplit(rownames(a), "-")),
            a[, "p adj"]
        ), c("Var1","var 2", "p") )
    a <- subset(a[stats::complete.cases(a),], p < signif.cutoff)
    if (nrow(a) == 0) return(p1) else {
        a$p <- formatC(signif(a$p, digits = 3),
                          digits = 3, format = "g", flag = "#")
        keep.tests <- unname(t(apply(a[, -3], 1, sort)))
        keep.tests <- unname(split(keep.tests, seq(dim(keep.tests)[1])))
    ts <- list(a = a, keep.tests = keep.tests)
    p1 + ggsignif::geom_signif(
        comparisons=ts$keep.tests,
        test="TukeyHSD",
        annotations=ts$a$p, 
        step_increase=0.1)
    }
}

plot_grid(plotlist=lapply(names(dfl), doPlots, signif.cutoff=.2), ncol=3)

after running the code I get the following error

Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

I am attaching the output that i am actually expecting. In my case instead of analyste it would be type of roof (Banco or Toles) an dht eLabels would the the intervention type (control, soprema, sika, EPS).

Can someone help me figure out the error in my code?

Comment: In some places you refer to `Type` and `Roof` and in others `type` and `roof`. The sample data also only contains one factor level for each of these variables: `CONTROLE` and `Banco` and the error indicates 2 or more are needed. Probably best also to test your `ggplot` with 1 data frame before generalising to a function.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I found my error and corrected the plot.